# Why does continuing too soon on a breakpoint make my server send an invalid response

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-8

I'm returning a video file through IIS for a range request in a WCF service.

The end of the code looks like this:

```
WriteResponseHeaders(stuff);
while (remainingBytes > 0)
{
    if (response.IsClientConnected) // response is a System.Web.HttpResponse
    {
        int chunkSize = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10240 < remainingBytes ? 10240 : remainingBytes);
        response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
        remainingBytes -= chunkSize;
        response.Flush();
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

In Firefox, Internet Explorer and Opera it works correctly. In Chrome, the video will stop playing a while before the end. Fiddler shows a 504 error:

> [Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request. Server returned 16556397 bytes.

If I stick a breakpoint just after the loop, and let the program sit there until the video has progressed past its stopping point, Chrome will play the full video without any problem and Fiddler will show the response with all of the correct headers and such. The only code that gets executed between that breakpoint and the end of the call is to flush the log stream.

As a test, I stuck in:

```
while (response.IsClientConnected)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

after the loop and playback was fine in all browsers. My response also looked fine in Fiddler. Of course this has way too many problems to be a proper solution, but it seems to show me that this is an issue more of timing than of behaviour.

Why does allowing the code to progress past this point too soon cause a problem and how do I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try returning a Stream instead of writing to the response.OutputStream.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStreamingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/video?id={id}")]
    Stream GetVideo(string id);
}

public class StreamingService : IStreamingService
{
    public System.IO.Stream GetVideo(string id)
    {
        Stream stream = File.OpenRead("c:\\Temp\\Video.mp4");
        //WriteResponseHeaders(stuff);
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Update:

If you want to support seeking you can either copy the chunk into a byte[] and return a MemoryStream or you could wrap your stream in a proxy that only returns a part of your full file.

```
public class PartialStream : Stream
{
    private Stream underlying;

    private long offset;

    private long length;

    public PartialStream(Stream underlying, long offset, long length)
    {
        this.underlying = underlying;
        this.offset = offset;
        if (offset + length > underlying.Length) {
            this.length = underlying.Length - offset;
        } else {
            this.length = length;
        }

        this.underlying.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }

    public override bool CanSeek { get { return false; } }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return this.length; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return this.underlying.Position - offset;
        }
        set
        {
            this.underlying.Position = offset + Math.Min(value,this.length) ;
        }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (this.Position + offset >= this.length)
            return 0;

        if (this.Position + offset + count > this.length) {
            count = (int)(this.length - this.Position - offset);
        }


        return underlying.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        this.underlying.Dispose();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

And you have to respect the Range request header.

```
public System.IO.Stream GetVideo(string id)
{
    RangeHeaderValue rangeHeader;

    bool hasRangeHeader = RangeHeaderValue.TryParse(
                WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Range"], 
                out rangeHeader);

    var response = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;
    Stream stream = File.OpenRead("c:\\Temp\\Video.mp4");

    var offset = hasRangeHeader ? rangeHeader.Ranges.First().From.Value : 0;

    response.Headers.Add("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    response.ContentType = "video/mp4";

    if (hasRangeHeader) {
        response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
        var totalLength = stream.Length;
        stream = new PartialStream(stream, offset, 10 * 1024 * 1024);


        var header = new ContentRangeHeaderValue(offset, offset + stream.Length - 1,totalLength);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Range", header.ToString());
    }
    response.ContentLength = stream.Length;

    return stream;
}
```

Comment: This works to serve up the full video, but I lose the ability to seek within it.

Comment: @MikeBeaton That's not true. You can also return Partial Content. I've updated my answer with a concrete example.

Comment: Thanks, it was as simple as returning a properly-offset MemoryStream. I still have no idea why timing affected my previous implementation, but this solves the problem.